# Eclipse Project Starts With Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm following along with the beginners tutorial for android development in Eclipse.

I followed the instructions given in the tutorial for starting the project to the letter, and yet it begins with errors that make it so you can't even run the test "`hello world`" program.

The container '`Android Dependencies`' references non existing library

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Android 
Development\Workspace\appcompat_v7_2\bin\appcompat_v7_2.jar'
```

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved `appcompat_v7_2`

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved `MyFirstApp`

This confuses me greatly, and these errors are not addressed in the tutorial.

I'd appreciate any help in resolving these errors so that I can hopefully learn something.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have jar in place i.e in the given path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have this problem 30min ago and basically `appcompat_v7_2` is a bug from eclipse that you need to delete that folder from your package explorer.

After you delete it clean and build then

Create a new project again and set the minimum required SDK to 14

Comment: @Nifty62 you are in right track an make android project again. and youll see that inimum required SDK: put it to 14

Comment: Please forgive me since I'm new, but doesn't that limit the android devices that can use this application?

Comment: @Nifty62 yes but you can change it later its just when you set it to 8 it will make that folder again the one that you deleted

Comment: Ok, I did it and you are right, there are no longer any errors. But now I don't see the default "hello world", which isn't a problem, but when I hit 'Run as Android Application' nothing happens in the emulator. I could be wrong, but the tutorial tells me to run it and I thought something was supposed to happen, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: @Nifty62 not that is located in your layout folder youll see 2 xml in the one name activity main go check if there is a textview in there

Comment: There is nothing in the layout tags besides the properties for the layout itself. I tried putting one in, but that gave me an error of it's own. I haven't gotten far enough in the tutorial to understand how to do it lol.

Comment: @Nifty62 ya just followm first the biggerners layout to understand some basics